# ng-cloak is not hidding buttons before scope is loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I´m having trouble using ng-cloak. I have 2 buttons and only one is shown ate each time.
i have a property in my controller that shows one or the other button. Ng-cloak should hide both buttons if the scope is not set right ?

Could i get any help please ?

Thank you

Comment: `ng-cloak` only hides elements until angular is loaded/bootstrapped.

Comment: Do you have a sugestion to hide both buttons and only show after scope is loaded ?

Comment: I think there is another problem, can you post your code?

Comment: Just use `ng-if` or `ng-show` with appropriate conditions.